# Distribution of the lowest value among $n$ throws of a die

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

Throwing a die $N $times, the random variable $X$ is the lowest value from all of the $N$ throws. 
For ($1 \leq i \leq 6$) how to find $P(X=i)$?

Example:
$n=5$, throws=$(6,3,4,4,5) \implies X=3$

Comment: Hint:  it is easier to compute the probability that $P(X≥i)$.  You can then get the value you want by subtracting.  That is, $P(X=j)=P(X≥j)-P(X≥j+1)$.

Comment: Thank you lulu very helpful hint.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, with $i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

- the probability all $N$ dice values are greater than or equal to $i$ is $\left(\frac{7-i}{6}\right)^N$
- the probability all $N$ dice vales are strictly greater than  $i$ is $\left(\frac{6-i}{6}\right)^N$
- the probability the lowest value of $N$ dice is exactly  $i$ is $\left(\frac{7-i}{6}\right)^N - \left(\frac{6-i}{6}\right)^N$

So the probability the lowest value of $5$ dice is exactly  $3$ is $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^5 - \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^5 =\frac{781}{7776} \approx 0.1$.  The distribution with $N=5$ dice is

```
Lowest  Prob
  1    0.59812
  2    0.27019
  3    0.10044
  4    0.02713
  5    0.00399
  6    0.00013
```